# How can I simplfy this logic

Tags: php, conditional-statements, logic, if-statement

I'm having trouble simplifying this conditional statements logic. Is there a more effervescent way of writing this?

```
if(($x || $a) && ($x || $y))
{
   if($x){
          return true;
   }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if ($x) return true;
return false;
```

According to your statement, you only return true if `$x` is true, therefore that is the only statement you really need to check for, correct? The variables `$a` and `$y` are completely irrelevant.

**Edit:** Same thing as:

```
return (bool) $x;
```

Comment: He might want to do that if and only if one of `$a`, `$y` is `true`.

Comment: I would use `return (bool) $x;`

Comment: @The machine Charmer: But even in the first statement, if `$x` is true then both of the statements become true automatically. If `$x || $a` and `$x || $y` are both true if `$x` is true, therefore the && between them makes the overall statement true as well.

Comment: @Gumbo: That would be good. :) @fastcodejava: No one said `$x` was a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

If you only return true if $x is true, then the rest of the code is irrelevant. Thus,

```
return (bool) $x;
```

EDIT: Oops... bool is a cast, not a function.

Answer (score 2):

The condition of the outer `if`, `($x || $a) && ($x || $y)`, is equivalent to `$x || ($a && $y)`. When we conjunct that with the condition that `$x` must also be *true* (inner `if`), we get `($x || ($a && $y)) && $x`. And that is equivalent to `$x && $x || $x && $a && $y` which can be reduced to `$x || $x && $a && $y`. In both OR branches `$x` must be *true* to proceed. But if the `$x` in the right branch is *true*, the whole condition is already *true*.

So the only variable that needs to be *true* is `$x`:

```
return (bool) $x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like several people have already said, only $x matters in your code. I guess the shortest possible code is:

```
return $x
```

Comment: What if `$x` is a string or a number? Then it does not return a boolean true/false.

Comment: You are right. Seems like we do need the if($x) return true; else return false, then. Anyway, why have a method for this at all when the only thing it does is to check the value of $x...

Comment: I don't know, it seems like it would be a good school assignment, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if($x){
          return true;
   }

   return false;
```

?

Edit:

```
return $x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($x && ($a || $y))
     return true;

return false;
```

Comment: That’s semantically not the same. `($x || $a) && ($x || $y)` is equivalent to `$x || ($a && $y)` and `$x && ($a || $y)` to `($x || $a) && ($x || $y)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(($x && $a && $y)
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

**EDIT** : it is simply `return $x;`

Answer (score 0):

You could write this as a one line expression...

```
return $x;
```

regardless of $a and $y, $x has to be true to return true